# Получить массив значений полей ID из массива объектов

Tags: javascript

У меня есть два массива `['Text1', 'Text2'], [{id:1, name: "Text1"},{id:2, name:'Text2'}]`
Мне нужно создать третий массив чтобы в нем были значения ключей id из второго массива, соответствующие элементам массива `['Text1', 'Text2']`
Т.е. третий массив должен быть таким `[1,2]` Если у меня в первом массиве будет только один элемент, то третий массив должен содержать только один элемент ID. Т.е. если `['Text2']`, третий массив будет `[2]`, а если `['Text1']` то `[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr1 = ['Text1', 'Text2'];
const arr2 = ['Text1'];
const arr3 = ['Text2'];
const arr5 = ['Text1', 'Text777', 'Text2'];
const arr4 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Text1"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Text2'
}];

function getArr(first, second) {
  return first.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const val = second.find(el => el.name === item);
    return val ? [...acc, val.id] : acc;
   // return val ? [...acc, undefined] : acc; // на случай, если надо вернуть undefined
  }, []);
}



console.log(getArr(arr1, arr4))
console.log(getArr(arr2, arr4))
console.log(getArr(arr3, arr4))
console.log(getArr(arr5, arr4))
```

Comment: А ошибка как раз таки здесь `['Text1', 'Text777', 'Text2']` -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Придется проверять на случай отсутствия например Text111
const arr1 = ['Text1', 'Text111', 'Text2']
const arr2 = [{ id: 1, name: "Text1" }, { id: 2, name: 'Text2' }, { id: 555, name: 'Text555' }]

const arr = arr2.reduce((a, { id, name }) => {
  // Проверка на случай отсутствия записи
  let ind = arr1.findIndex((v) => v === name)
  if (ind !== -1) {
    a[ind] = id
  }
  return a
}, [])

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: В результате ошибка, `[ 1, undefined, 2]` . Советую также сделать reduce не у второго массива, а у первого.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin Так ведь это не ошибка, это пропуск, что'б индексы элементов `id` соответствовали индексам первого массива, `undefined` как раз и означает отсутствие `id`.